# What can i say about the following afirmation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$ 4^{2n} - 1 , n \ge 1 $ is multiple of $15$.

1. Its false
2. $ 4^{2n} - 1, n \ge 1 $ is a multiple of $3$, but is just a multiple of $5$ depending on the value of $ n \ge 1 $
3. $ 4^{2n} - 1, n \ge 1 $ is a multiple of $5$, but is just a multiple of $3$ depending on the value of $ n \ge 1 $
4. $ 4^{2n} - 1, n \ge 1 $ is a multiple of $15$

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that $x^n-1 = (x-1)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + \ldots + x +1).$

Answer (score 1):

$$4^{2n}-1=16^n-1=16\underbrace{(16^{n-1}-1)}+16-1$$

Hence by induction $\cdots$